# getting string representation of function from a list having function name and arguments

Tags: python

I just want to know if there is some way in Python to make function and its arguments from the list and store them in a variable that can be passed to `eval`

e.g. :

```
def dummyfunction(title):
    print "Hello %s" %(title)
```

Normal way to invoke this function is :
`dummyfunction("John")`

I am having the function name and its arguments inside the list as `list1 = ['dummyfunction', 'John']`.My requirement is to get a string representation of this function as `dummyfunction("John")` which can be used as an input to `eval` function since it takes string argument.

Comment: i didn't get you, but did you mean that you wanted to design a function that takes a list as its parameter and prints "Hello" and all the values in a list? if yes then check my answer. There is high ambiguity in this question though..

Comment: I just looked at my code again and my actual requirement is to get a string representation of a function from the list which can be passed to eval

Comment: then what do you want? @sarbjit

Comment: Using `eval` is not a requirement. That is an implementation constraint. There is no possible reason for that to be a constraint.

Comment: @Marcin but we dont know in what context is sarbjit using this and hence we have to assume that he wants to pass it to eval and answer accordingly

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi I know that in every possible context, using python, there is no reason whatsoever to use eval, because functions can be looked up by name in a variety of ways.

Comment: true enough, but we dont know what sarbjit is up to.. @Marcin

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi Once again, whatever he is up to (and I do know what that is), there is no reason to use eval.

Comment: I don't know why people are downvoting the question. If you want to downvote, state the reason as well. I think this site is for posting problems only. Now I know, depending upon the person grip over an language, question contents may vary. So what you want, no questions from beginners or who have just started learning language. Well based on answers below, I learnt lot of other concepts along with solution to my problem about which I was not aware earlier.

Comment: @sarbjit You're being downvoted  because "use eval" is not a requirement, it's a bogus implementation constraint. You're being downvoted for asking how to shoot yourself in the foot, without any apparent awareness that will hurt.

Comment: @Marcin Thanks! My point was I haven't used eval so far, then just by simply downvoting, how would I know that I need not have to use eval. Atleast now, I know that I should not use the eval.

Comment: @sarbjit The point is not that you should have known not to use eval, the point is that this was an unnecessary (and improper) implementation constraint which you kept repeating was a requirement. This makes this a poor question, because it poses a non-existent problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you can, instead of putting the name of the function, just put the function itself in a list:

```
sexpression = [dummyfunction,1,2,3]
sexpression[0](*sexpression[1:])
```

If the function is an object method, then you can use `getattr`:

```
strpression = ['dummyfunction',1,2,3]
getattr(myobj,strpression[0])(*strpression[1:])
```

If it's in a known module, you can do the exact same thing with the module object in place of `myobj`

Because you can look up a function by name, there is no reason to ever use `eval` to call a function. Don't do it.

Finally, if you want to collect arbitrary functions together for lookup by name you can do:

```
namespace = {'dummyfunction': dummyfunction}
#or
namespace = {f.__name__:f for f in [dummyfunction]}
```

Comment: I just looked at my code again and my actual requirement is to get a string representation of a function from the list which can be passed to eval

Comment: @sarbjit Why is your requirement to use `eval`? You can invoke the function without using `eval`, which raises numerous security issues.

Comment: Actually I am implementing a console app using Tkinter. I am aware of all the security related issues with `eval` and I will be using proper namespace to expose only my app related functions to users. Right now if write some thing like from my console app `dummyfunction("John")`, it works. I want to make it work if I write like `dummyfunction "John"` in console eliminating the requirement to use paranthesis. I hope it clears my requirement. Sorry I was not clear at first place.

Comment: @sarbjit You do not need to use eval to do that. You can just look up the function by name in a dict or module.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't understand on how to do it? So, I have a string/list being read from my console. Now how would I execute the command? Right now I am reading the command from console, making it a string and using the `eval` and finally printing the output to my console app.

Comment: So, I tried it like `list1[0](list1[1:])` (without use of eval) and it said string is not callable. Is it correct way to use?

Comment: @anshuman, I checked it. Now I am not using the `eval` and using the globals to get function name and calling it.

Comment: Do not use eval, ever, understood?

Comment: @Apero, Yeah I got it not to use `eval` after three downvote :)

Answer (score 1):

If the function is defined as module global, you can use `globals`:

```
func = globals()[list1[0]]
func(list1[1])
```

But above code could cause any abitrary function to be called. If you don't want that, use following form.

```
funcs = {
    'dummyfunction': dummyfunction,
}
func = funcs[list1[0]]
func(list1[1])
```

Comment: I just looked at my code again and my actual requirement is to get a string representation of a function from the list which can be passed to eval

Comment: +1 actually pretty good answer, it's strange it's not upvoted more

Answer (score -2):

if you just wanted a string representation of the function call to pass into eval then you can do this:

```
eval("dummyFunction(\"John\")")
#or
eval("dummyFunction('John')")
```

if you had a list with function name and argument then do this:

```
list1 = ['dummyfunction', 'John']
eval(list1[0]+"('"+list1[1]+"')")
```

Answer (score -3):

Is the first reference in the list really the string name of the function, or is it the function object itself?  If it's the function object itself, you can do this:

```
list[0](*list[1:])
```

If it's really the string name, you can try:

```
globals()[list[0]](*list[1:])
```

Note that this will only work if your function is defined in the global namespace.  If it's in a local namespace, or a class or something, then you'll need to get the function from that namespace, instead of globals().

Comment: For the downvoters, I'd appreciate some feedback as to why this is a bad solution.